# svg <use> doesn't work with iframe innerHTML in FF

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, svg

I have a svg symbol in the string and I need to append it to the iframe body.

I tried to use just an innerHTML of the body element and it's works fine in Chrome and IE, but doesn't work in FF:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

setTimeout(function(){
  iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = '<svg class="multi"><use xlink:href="#multi"></use></svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol viewBox="0 0 512 512" id="multi"><style type="text/css"> .st0{fill:#D8F4FF;} </style> <path d="M223.7,256.5L113.7,146.6l34.9-34.9l109.9,109.9l107.8-107.8l34.9,34.9L293.6,256.5l107.8,107.8l-34.9,34.9L258.6,291.5L148.7,401.4l-34.9-34.9L223.7,256.5z"/></symbol></svg>';
}, 100);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk1ygjvp/)

Why it's doesn't work? And how can I fix it?

Comment: about:blank#multi works but I don't think that's such a great solution. Perhaps you should raise a bugzilla bug.

Comment: reported the bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1175073